# Finding on any key in ElasticSearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

We have an index of Users with Cars e.g.

```
{
   "name": "Eli",
   "cars": {
        "Honda": { "color": "Red", "Price": 120 },
        "Toyota":{ "color": "Blue", "Price": 110 }
        "Mazda": { "color": "White", "Price": 100 }
   }
}

{
   "name": "Eli",
   "cars": {
        "Honda": { "color": "Blue", "Price": 110 },
        "BMW": { "color": "Red", "Price": 200 }
   }
}
```

We are trying to retrieve all the users with a Red Car.

```
cars.*.color = "Red"
```

But we couldn't find a way to do it in ElasticSearch.

Comment: Please share the mapping. `GET /index_name/type_name/_mapping`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `query_string` query like this:

```
POST index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "cars.\\*.color:Red"
    }
  }
}
```